# Why can't we launch QGIS.exe? Why we have to use QGIS.bat?

Tags: qgis

QGIS.bat - it is calling some other batch files (all of them also setting up path variable and some more variables), sets some more variables and setting up PATH.  I have done that in system properties. Still I am not able to directly launch the QGIS.exe

If I run through QGIS.bat then it is launching fine.

Comment: As you said, because of the paths

Comment: I had setup all those variables, including PATH in the windows environment variables.

Comment: Because QGIS don't use the windows environment variables

Comment: @gene Please post your comments as an answer so this can be marked as resolved

Comment: Done -------------------

Answer (score 2):

Because QGIS don't use the windows environment variables

Comment: For QGIS 3.0, work on normal exe-based loading is under way https://twitter.com/madmanwoo/status/832925367778226176